# Which is faster, the concatenator or the PHP native function

Tags: php

When I want to get a few bits of the string

`$str = 'abcd' ;`
Most people use 
`substr ( $str, 0, 2 ) ;`
Why not
`$prefix = $str[0] . $str[1] ;`

Comment: I think `substr` is to extract part of a string while the `$str[0] . $str[1]` is to combine string together.

Comment: Well if you wanted the first 3 it would be `$prefix = $str[0] . $str[1] . $str[2];`. So the more you want the longer the expression will be, with `subst` it will always be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running both functions 100.000 times to get a reasonably acceptable measurement:

```
<?php

$str = 'abcd';

$before = microtime(true);

for ($i=0 ; $i<100000 ; $i++) {
    substr($str, 0, 2);
}

$after = microtime(true);

echo ($after-$before)/$i . " sec/substr\n";

$before = microtime(true);

for ($i=0 ; $i<100000 ; $i++) {
    $str[0] . $str[1] ;
}

$after = microtime(true);

echo ($after-$before)/$i . " sec/concatenate\n";

?>
```

Produces the following result:

> 4.8739910125732E-8 sec/substr
>   5.666971206665E-8 sec/concatenate

Running it multiple times gives an average of between 0.3 and 0.6 seconds difference where `substr()` is faster than concatenation. I suppose this has to do with that fact that `substr()` only requires one operation while `$str[0] . $str[1]` requires 3 operations (get both values and concatenation itself). I suspect the differences will increase depending on the amount of operations needed.

Comment: I believe the code can be optimized if you put the $str = 'abcd'; outside of your loops. You don't have to declare it again and again .

Comment: @andrew Hmm maybe. I decided to do it this way as with any real environment the variable declaration would be in there as well. But you are right, it is better for optimization :)

Comment: @andrew Optimized it. Surprisingly enough it didn't make any difference in execution time. In fact, it even increased sometimes, haha

Comment: ??? strange. I would expect better times since there are few vars declared... oh well

Answer (score 1):

how about being dynamic? :D

```
echo implode(" ", $Arrayofstrings );
```

Comment: We can use intermediate variable.

Answer (score 1):

To see what is faster, just search for benchmark:

The winner is `substr`, it's the fastest function for this kind of operation.

[Test: substr($var, 5, 1) vs. isset && {5}](http://www.spudsdesign.com/benchmark/index.php?t=substr4&history)

[Complete Test Menu](http://www.spudsdesign.com/benchmark/index.php)

Answer (score 1):

**PHP 5**

`substr` is slow than concatenator, if you want the fastest execution approach, it is

`"$str[0]$str[1]"`

**PHP 7**

JIT and calling convertion in PHP7 are optimized, so a call to `substr` is much faster than that in PHP5

Comment: Oh,well.Thanks.Is there any other way that is faster than "$str[0]$str[1]" in PHP7. We are using PHP7.